# unexpected error with php fileinfo extension usage (windows wamp)

Tags: php, file-upload, wamp, mime-types

I am using current wamp of wampserver.com under windows7 (Apache : 2.4.9, PHP : 5.5.12 ). file upload script was having troubles with file info functions. Troubles that i dont have with linux lamp and professinal hosting companies. Finfo class not found was the error. I added this statement into php.ini to use finfo under win7 wamp

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

I am able to use file info objects and functions. But a weird error shows up when i try to destroy finfo object.

Error:

```
Warning: finfo_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Script:

```
...
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$semamime = $finfo->file($_FILES['filedata']['tmp_name']);
if (false === $ext = array_search(
      $finfo->file($_FILES['filedata']['tmp_name']),
      array(
          'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
      ),
      true
)) {
throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}
!!!! finfo_close($finfo); !!!
...
```

file exists. i am seing the ANSI form of the file content on the screen. i gave the legitimate parameter to the finfo_close but no luck. Is this error about my syntax or the wamp that im using?

**EDIT**

Complete script: http://pastebin.com/x8Bbv5S4

php.ini file   : http://pastebin.com/9KjVjThU (extension activated at the last line)

Comment: are you sure extension=php_fileinfo.dll has no semicolon?

Comment: positive. Before erasing semicolon, first line was giving error. Now its the finfo_close()

Comment: @kimbarcelona i posted the file

Comment: The [examples for `finfo_open` in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php#refsect1-function.finfo-open-examples) only show `finfo_close` being used when the procedural style with `finfo_open` is used – in the first example for the object-oriented style (`new finfo(…)`) you’ll notice that there is no call to `finfo_close` there … so I’d assume that it is simply not needed in this case.

Comment: you are right. its weird that i copied this from my other script which works flawlessly at remote lamp. I think hosting company omitting php errors.

Comment: @CBroe feel free to post former answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [examples for `finfo_open` in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php#refsect1-function.finfo-open-examples) only show `finfo_close` being used when the procedural style with `finfo_open` is used – in the first example for the object-oriented style (`new finfo(…)`) you’ll notice that there is no call to `finfo_close` there … so I’d assume that it is simply not needed in this case.